# How to convert integer into date format in r?

Tags: r, date, integer

Hi I have a column which is named as Week but is of class integer. It looks like this

`Week
201401
201402
201403
201404`

These are essentially the weeks in 2014. I want to convert them into week ending dates like

201401 = 2014-01-05

201402 = 2014-01-12

Thank You.

Ps. I tried to google the answer for this but could not get the relevant one. Also as.Date does not work for me.

Thanks again.

Comment: It appears you have rules for where the first week starts.  Please explain, and post your attempts at a solution.

Comment: No I just opened the windows calendar and checked for the first week and it ended in '2014-01-05'. Any way of converting this integer type to date will help

Comment: So you're looking for the week-**ending** dates?  This information should be in the question as well, along with your attempts.

Comment: Please explain why the first few google hits for "R convert year week to date" doesn't help you.

Comment: I still cannot figure out how to convert it completely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
dates <- c(201401, 201402, 201403, 201404)
as.Date(paste0(dates, '-0'), format = "%Y%W-%w")

# [1] "2014-01-05" "2014-01-12" "2014-01-19" "2014-01-26"
```

`%W` is the week number and we had the `-0` to get the last day (Sunday) of the week (`%w` goes from 0 to 6).

You can look at `help("strptime")` to get more information on dates manipulation.